# Is it possible to send an object in a GET request using postman?

Tags: postman

I have been trying to send an object in a GET request but the object is always null. How do I do this?

Comment: GET requests are for reading data. You'll need to use a different HTTP method depending on your usecase like POST or PUT if you want to send request bodies.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

[Vasan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315419/vasan) already answered you in the comments: the purpose of GET requests is to get the resource specified by the path and the query params, so **it should not be used to send any kind of data to the server**.

If you need to send some kind of data to the server, you should better use the POST (probably) or PUT methods.

You can find some basic information about HTTP methods on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)